# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DelegateFactoryDelegate implementation was found

Tags: java, discord

I am trying to copy my discord bot to a new project.  I copied over everything exactly, but I'm still getting this error:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.javacord.api.DiscordApiBuilder.<init>(DiscordApiBuilder.java:33)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DelegateFactoryDelegate implementation was found!
        at org.javacord.api.util.internal.DelegateFactory.<clinit>(DelegateFactory.java:74)
        ... 2 more
```

Main file:

```
import org.javacord.api.DiscordApi;
import org.javacord.api.DiscordApiBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String token = "......";

        DiscordApi api = new DiscordApiBuilder()
                .setToken(token)
                .login()
                .join();
        api.addListener(new Spotting());
    }
}
```

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Infinity_Raiding_Tool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javacord</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacord</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  It works fine in my old project but not this new one.  Please help me figure this out.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: is Spotting() a class on the same package? Are you using the same pom dependencies versions on both projects?

Comment: Yes it is in the same package. Yes, I copied the dependencies exactly from the prevous project.

Comment: It's likely an issue with your jar building. You have to use the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to get a properly shaded jar that includes all transitive dependencies. Make sure you use maven to build your jars and not some other IDE builder.

Comment: That did it.  I was using IntelliJ to do my mvn build.  When I tried it in cmd it fixed the issue.  Thank you @Minn